# jqgrid - Is there a way to add some columns to column chooser not all columns?

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a way to add some columns to `columnchooser` not all columns? I have a `jqgrid` which create some columns dynamically on that. So, I want the columns that I created dynamically add to `jqgrid` not to `columnchooser` or after creation they show directly in the grid. So, it doesn't need the user goes to the `columnchooser` and select those columns to show.

I used below code for showing `columnchooser`:

```
 $('#enter-value-table-settings-dialog').columnchooser(
                    $("#enterValueGrid"), { 
                         titleText:  ($('<div/>').html($T('enter.value.edit.table')).text()),
                         style:'ish-columnchooser-title',
                         tableType: 13
                 });
            $('#Enter-value-table-settings').click(function() {   
                $('#enter-value-table-settings-dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `hidedlg: true` property in column definition of columns which you don't want to show in `columnChooser`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want those field always be in the column chooser. I just want when the grid load, all columns show in the grid (All checked). And I want that be in the dialog that I put the code above.

Comment: I want those dynamic field always show up after creation. Because normally when a column creates it goes to colummchooser first and the user has to click in columnchooser to show that field in the grid. I want the field always show up.